# Mudblazor : Date format in mudblazor table?

Tags: c#, mudblazor

In Mudblazor table, How can I format the date as "dd/MMM/yyyy" ?

```
    <MudTd DataLabel="Number">@context.ProjectNumber</MudTd>
    <MudTd DataLabel="Title">@context.ProjectTitle</MudTd>
    *<MudTd DataLabel="Date Of RFQ">@context.DateOfRFQ"</MudTd>*
```

[modified the date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbcqL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a String and use the Strings .ToString Format overload:

```
 <MudTd DataLabel="Date Of RFQ">@Convert.ToDateTime(@context.DateOfRFQ).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</MudTd>
```

As noted you needed to convert the value DateOfRFQ to a DateTime first to overcome the error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: I got exception: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

Comment: Hmm weird, does it work if you add a `DateOfRFQString` string member to the model?

Comment: Ok I got it. <MudTd DataLabel="Date Of RFQ">@Convert.ToDateTime(@context.DateOfRFQ).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</MudTd>